# How to Load a DLL in multiple threads in Delphi?

Tags: windows, multithreading, delphi, dll, delphi-6

Maybe there is something that I missed, I can't figure what is happening here.

I'm trying to load the same DLL in multiple instances of a TThread Object.

Here is my DLL code:

```
library MyCalcFor32;

uses
  SysUtils,
  Classes,
  uRunner in 'uRunner.pas';

Exports EVal;

{$R *.res}

begin
end.
```

This is the uRunner.pas:

```
unit uRunner;

interface

uses SysUtils,
     Classes;

function EVal(Valor: WideString): WideString; stdcall; export;

implementation

function EVal(Value: WideString): WideString; stdcall; export;
begin
  Result := Value+' xxx';
end;

initialization

finalization

end.
```

This is the program to Load the DLL:

```
procedure TfrmMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var I: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Threads, 10);
  for I:= 0 to 9 do
  begin
    Threads[I] := TWorker.Create(Self.Handle, I+1, Memo1.Text, ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)));
  end;
end;


procedure TfrmMain.btnExecuteThreadsClick(Sender: TObject);
var I: Integer;
begin
  ClearMemos([MT1, MT2, MT3, MT4, MT5, MT6, MT7, MT8, MT9, MT10]);

  for I:= 0 to 0 do //to 9, for multiple
  begin
    if Threads[I].Suspended then
      Threads[I].Resume
    else
      ShowMessage('Thread already in execution');
  end;
end;

procedure TWorker.Execute;
var I: Integer;
    J: Cardinal;

    Ret: WideString;

    A,B,C: Extended;       
begin
  CoInitialize(nil);
  try
    LoadDll;

    while not Terminated do
    begin
      if not (Suspended or Terminated) then
      begin
        A := 310132041025;
        B := 17592186044416;
        C := 0;

        for I:= 0 to 10 do
        begin

          if (Terminated) then begin
            Break;
          end;

          for J:= 0 to 9999999 do
          begin

            if (Terminated) then begin
              Break;
            end;

            A:= Sqrt(A);

            if A <= 0 then begin
              A:= 310132041025;
            end
            else begin
              A:= Math.Power(A, 2);
            end;

            C:= C + (B-34 / 4);

            B:= B / 2;

            if B <= 0 then begin
              B:= 17592186044416;
            end;
          end;

          Ret := FEvalProcAddress(FEValValue);

          NotifyMainForm(Format('Evaluate %s, resulted in %s', [IntToStr(I), Ret]));
        end;
        Suspend;
      end;

      Sleep(5000);
    end;
  finally
    CoUninitialize;
  end;
end;  

procedure TWorker.LoadDll;
begin
  //GlobalLock.Enter;
  //try
    FDLLHandle := LoadLibraryA(PChar(FPathApp + 'MyCalcFor32.dll'));
  //finally
  //  GlobalLock.Leave;
  //end;

  if GetLastError <> 0 then
  begin
    NotifyTerminateThread;
  end
  else
  begin
    FEvalProcAddress := GetProcAddress(FDLLHandle, PChar('EVal'));

    if GetLastError <> 0 then
    begin
      NotifyTerminateThread;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

When I have only 1 thread, it works just fine, but when I use multiple threads It raises the following exception:

```
System Error.  Code: 87.
Incorrect Parameter
```

Note: The above code is just for reproduction; 
      I am aware of WideString + AnsiString problem.

Comment: `export` is pointless. You may as well remove it. And the `register` calling convention means you can only call this function from Delphi.

Comment: I forgot, I just put stdcall. I'll edit the question

Comment: It is useless to check inside a thread if it is suspended. If you suspend a thread then there is no more action inside this thread. Thats why `TThread.Suspend`/`TThread.Resume` is now deprecated. You should better use events

Comment: @SirRufo As you can see I am using Delphi 6, so, Suspend/Resume is not deprecated.

Comment: Although it is not deprecated in Delphi 6, it is wise **not** to use it. And checking for `TThread.Suspended` inside the thread shows up, that you did not understand whats going on on `TThread.Suspend`

Comment: I understand that suspend, stops the user code. So it's useless indeed. Except in cases where I want the user code stops first than the OS stops my thread, in this case checking it doesn't make sense. but in the production code, it does.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are performing the error checking incorrectly. You are only meant to call `GetLastError` if the function fails. I expect that you are calling `GetLastError` after an API call that succeeded and not all API calls do `SetLastError(0)` when they return success. So you are picking up a stale error code that does not apply to the function call that you made.

To check for failure, for these functions, you need to examine the return value.

- `LoadLibrary` reports failure by returning `0`.
- `GetProcAddress` reports failure by returning `nil`.

You have to read the documentation of the functions carefully, but this is a very common theme. Each Win32 API function may potentially handle errors differently. Read the docs for each function individually.

Comment: I'd bet this one is on the "All-time API Usage Mistakes Top Ten" list, if there is such thing.